# Does the front door of the TARDIS always open up to the control room?

Tags: doctor-who, tardis, gravity

In all of the episodes of Doctor Who that I've seen the TARDIS' front door opens up to the control room. However, it would seem that given the TARDIS' capabilities it would be possible for the door to open up to *any* internal space within the TARDIS.

Has the front door of the TARDIS ever been shown to connect up to and open into another room besides the control room? I was prompted to ask based on [this related question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/23276/2287) dealing with gravity inside the TARDIS and the issue regarding how River was able to dive into the pool room of a *sideways* TARDIS in the episode [*Day of the Moon*](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Day_of_the_Moon_%28TV_story%29).

Comment: It might be worth mentioning how she enters the TARDIS and the measures Amy and Rory are advised to take.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Well I would say that clearly the TARDIS front door can at least open up to more than one of the control rooms.

The TARDIS has at least one alternative control room - as seen for a whole sequence of storylines in the Tom Baker period:

[image: TARDIS Alternative Control Room]

I think the front door operated in exactly the same way here - appearing to go from the control room straight outside.  This would appear to validate your idea that the front door can open elsewhere in the TARDIS interior. I wish I could recall a storyline where it opens to another room.

Comment: I loved the steampunk Baker-era control room. Talons of Weng-Chiang...

Comment: @ChrisB.Behrens Absolutely, my favorite period of Dr Who. It did coincide with me being about 10 years old though, perhaps that's why I like it so much.

Comment: During the Tom Baker and Peter Davidson eras, I got the impression that there was some kind of foyer between the door to the outside and the doorway into the control room. This hypothetical foyer could have had other doors or hallways leading off of it.

Comment: During one of the 1969 episodes of season 5 (or 6?) of the new series, they try to catch River who's jumping off a building. To not have her crash into some part of the TARDIS, the Doctor says to open up all doors to the swimming pool. Now, if you imagine her falling right through the front door into the control room first, wouldn't she crash into the center column/main controls? For me this would count as one way around this "always the control room", however couldn't he just have her fall straight into the pool? We probably never know...

Comment: @Mario "During one of the **1969** episodes of season 5 (or 6?)"?

Comment: @jim **The Impossible Astronaut** or the other one, always confusing the two names.

Comment: If you actually view _Masque of Mandragora_ you'll see that the Doctor and Sarah have to walk a _long_ way through the internal corridors in episode 1 before they arrive at the alternative control room. It does not open directly off the main doors. Some 1970s episodes even show that the traditional control room does not open directly off the doors: there are scenes which appear to indicate a corridor where the outside world would theoretically be, including _Claws of Axos_ ( see http://www.themindrobber.co.uk/tardis-set-history-console-room-design2.html).

Comment: @Ed999 ... I do recall them walking through the TARDIS, but that doesn't invalidate the idea that the door can open to different spaces insude.  You never or at least rarely see in the old Doctor Who the outside from the inside anyway, so its not clear that its directly to any of the control rooms.

Comment: I wish it was that simple, but...  In actual fact, back when William Hartnell was in the show it was possible to see out through the main doors from inside the control room, an effect first used in episode 2 of _An Unearthly Child_ (November 1963). This also used to happen when Jon Pertwee was in the show, for instance in episode 1 of _Colony In Space_ (1971). When Tom Baker took over, it continued to occur, for example in episode 2 of _Pyramids of Mars_ (1975).

Comment: @Ed999 ... but my point is that because you don't see this happen in the (relatively few) episodes in the alternative control room, doesn't mean it doesn't happen.  You don't see it frequently in the main control room.  You are definitely more of a Who scholar, and know episodes where it happens, but you must agree that it is far more common for them to just cut from the inside to the outside without showing  the outside from the inside. I'm curious as to your opinion, do you think the main control room is the only place that the door opens to?

Comment: Bearing in mind that many early episodes don't survive on film, it seems to have always been the case that the only occasions the exterior is seen through the doors is from the main control room. The alternative control room was only used for one season, but was never shown leading anywhere other than an interior corridor. For many years, until 1977 in 'The Invasion of Time', the concept that the Tardis had a vast interior simply didn't exist. So there was never any suggestion of the doors leading elsewhere than the control room. Hence I don't see any evidence to support such a large change.

Answer (score 8):

"Day of the Moon" provides some information on this, but I'm not sure whether it's an argument *for* or *against* the possibility:

> CANTON: She dove off a rooftop.
>   DOCTOR: Don't worry. She does that. **Amy, Rory, open all the doors to the swimming pool.**
>   (River turns into a dive, and plummets through the Tardis' open door where it is parked on the side of the skyscraper. **There is a big Splosh!** [sic, my copy is of questionable provenance])
>   <sup>*Doctor Who* (new series) S6E2 "Day of the Moon"</sup>

The "big splosh!" is not merely a sound effect but a visible splashing of water out of the TARDIS's front door, which suggests to me that the door was directly connected to the pool.  But it's not clear to me why the Doctor asked Amy and Rory to open the doors, plural.  I assume he was talking about doors internal to the TARDIS, rather than the front door.  That would mean she fell *through* the control room into the swimming pool.  And if he could just rearrange where the front door led, it seems like he wouldn't need them to open any internal doors.  Perhaps he wanted to make it easier for River to get back to the control room?  But she should know her own way around the TARDIS, since she can usually fly the thing better than the Doctor.

Out of universe, I suppose the writers put this in because they just needed to get the phrase "swimming pool" into the script (to explain River's survival) with as little unnecessary exposition as possible.  I doubt they were actually thinking about it at this level of detail. Perhaps even they don't know whether the Doctor can change the front door in this fashion.

So in conclusion, we just don't know.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose it is of interest to note that in Logopolis, the Tardis door led to the Tardis door .... though this was a trap set by the Master.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that that was the Tardis door changing to different places.I think the doctor can change the density of certain parts of the Tardis. I also recall an episode where the doctor says that the tardis can change itself to trap unwanted visitors in a room.Perhaps the tardis SWITCHES The Place of the Swimming pool to one door away so River could simply dodge the central console and land in the swimming Pool.

Comment: Perhaps. But is there reason to think it is one as opposed to the other?